# Prime or Not Prime from Interger in Function

Tags: c, primes

I don't understand why it does't output what it is supposed to. I have redone it three times, but it doesn't properly output if an `int` is a prime or not.

```
/**
 * Make a function called isprime that returns true (i.e. 1) if the integer
 * number passed to it is prime and false (i.e. 0) if it is composite (i.e.
 * not prime.)  A number is composite if it is divisible by 2 or any odd number
 * up to the square root of the number itself, otherwise it is prime.
 * Hint: n is divisible by m if (n % m == 0)
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int isprime(unsigned long long n) {
  unsigned long long m;
  for (m = 2; m <= n/m; m++) {
    if (n%m == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}

/**
 * Using the isprime function you made above, test if a number provided on the
 * command line is prime or not. The program should print a usage message if no
 * number is provided ("Usage: p4 <number>\n") and print a warning if the number
 * is less than 2 ("input number should be > 1\n") and should be able to handle
 * numbers greater than 4 billion.
 *
 * Example input/output:
 * ./p4 9872349901
 * 9872349901 is prime
 * ./p4 65
 * 65 is not prime
 */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;
  int result;

  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf ("Usage: p4 <number>\n");
    }
  n = atoi (argv[1]);

  if (n < 2)
    {
      printf ("input number should be > 1\n");
    }
  result = isprime (n);

  if (result == 1)
    printf ("%d is prime\n", n);
  else
    printf ("%d is not prime\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

UPDATED

After check compile:

```
> p4:
> Output of program (p4) is not correct for input '9872349871':
> ------ Yours: ------ 
> 1282415279 is not prime
> ---- Reference: ---- 
> 9872349871 is not prime
> --------------------
```

Comment: Change `n = atof (argv[1]);` to `n = atoi (argv[1]);`.  `atof` returns a `float` value, not an `int`.

Comment: `atof` converts a string to double, not int.

Comment: Begin by trying to build the code, and then fix the errors (and warnings!) that the compiler will show you. And you will get a few errors and warnings from that code shown.

Comment: Oh and please take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `isprime()` is declared with a `void` return value, yet is returning `int`s. That isn't going to work.

Comment: input? expected output? actual output?

Comment: Note: `for (m = 2; m <= n/m; m++)` finds non-primes a lot faster than `for (m = 2; m <= n - 1; m++)`

Comment: "should be able to handle numbers greater than 4 billion" - You can't do that with `int` or `long`. Floating point isn't well suited for determining primes. I'm not sure what technique your assignment is supposed to cover. Using `long long`? `fmod()`?

Comment: @FredLarson, I never heard of "long long" but I believe I heard of fmod() which it is for file mod?

Comment: @FredLarson, also yes you're right 'isprime()' isn't working but I always use this function often now but why isn't it working?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod for info on `fmod`. I can't see how your code is compiling with `isprime` declare to return `void`.

Comment: I am still confusing but what could I start with "isprime" on fmod?

Comment: Replace `n%m` with `fmod(n, m)`. But `n` and `m` as well as `n` in `main()` will have to be `double`. And you have to change your `printf` format specifier too.

Comment: Do you mean from ' int n; ' to ' double n; '?

Comment: `int n  .... int m; ... fmod(n, m)` makes no sense to use here versus `n%m`.

Answer (score 2):

> 'isprime()' isn't working but I always use this function often now but why isn't it working?

`void isprime (int n)` --> A return of `void` from a prime test makes no sense.  this is a fatal design flaw.

As `isprime(int n)` has `return 0;` to a `void isprime (int n)` function.  A  fatal error. This *should* spark warnings with a well enabled compiler.  **Enable all warnings to save time.**

`if ((fmod(n, m)) == 0)` makes no sense with `int` arguments `n,m`.  I'd expect `if (n%m == 0)`. Converting to floating point is hugely inefficient here and often incorrect as a prime test when `int` precision exceed `double`.

`int` range is often insufficient to values in the 4 billion range.  Recommend the widest *unsigned* type.  To handle `9872349901`, use `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t`. [@Fred Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091933/prime-or-not-prime-from-interger-in-function/53092861#comment93081125_53091933)

`for (m = 2; m <= n - 1; m++)` is painfully slow for large non-prime `n`.  Only iterate to the square root: when the quotient exceeds the divisor.

`isprime(0)` and `isprime(1)` return the wrong result.

**Alternate**

```
int isprime(unsigned long long n) {
  unsigned long long m;
  for (m = 2; m <= n/m; m++) {
    if (n%m == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}
```

*Many* performance optimization are possible for `isprime()`. [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Comment: 'p4:
-1.0 output of program (p4) is not correct for input '9872349871':
------ Yours: ------
1282415279 is not prime
---- Reference: ----
9872349871 is not prime
--------------------'

Comment: Sorry but I'm bad with formatting cause I'm new to SO

Comment: @MikeODell You are not using the correct type, or functions, or `printf()` specifiers in the calling code.  Still using `atoi()`?  To well convert strings to large integers research `strtoull()`, `strtoumax()`,`strtoll()`.  I did not attempt to list nor fix the various weaknesses with `main()`.  Hint: 9872349871 is 0x24C701AAF and 1282415279 is 0x4C701AAF.

Comment: What? I do not understand what do you mean but it's works when I compile and the result isn't correct.

Comment: The loop can be cut down to half the time by only bothering with odd numbers. I'd do the divide by 2 separately first then change the for loop to start at 3 and increment by two each time.

Comment: @waterjuice As mentioned in the answer, "Many performance optimization are possible".  The classic only check for even does not reduce the O() and so is only a minor improvement.  Keeping a list of prior known primes and/or the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) are quite significant improvements.